# Any way to use image with select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [awesomplete autocomplete plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete) and I'm trying to add image my select list for a months but I couldn't do  isn't there any way using image with autocomplete or select ?

I'm talking about this:

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input class="awesomplete" list="mylist" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option>Ada</option>
 <option>Java</option>
 <option>JavaScript</option>
 <option>Brainfuck</option>
 <option>LOLCODE</option>
 <option>Node.js</option>
 <option>Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

end I don't want to do with inline css because it's not cross browser

Comment: datalist isn't cross-browser either: http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions with different label and value are supported too. The label will be shown in autocompleter and the value will be inserted into the input.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="myinput" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myinput");

    // Show label but insert value into the input:
    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: [
            { label: "<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUxdD-Q4nIx3uIg9jBCe1oT5a9MHuWY5_pW4FoZSU-nQd1Y_WJPQ'/> Faceboock", value: "https://www.facebook.com/" },
            { label: "<img src='https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/2/25/Pounce_icon.png/16px-Pounce_icon.png?version=77c984fc4a9c8ca491ead081322fa738'/> Youtube", value: "https://www.youtube.com/" },
            { label: "China", value: "CN" },
            { label: "United States", value: "US" }
        ]
    });

    // You can search for a better version
    $(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click',function(e)
    {
        if($('#myinput').val())
            window.location = $('#myinput').val();
        //console.log($('#myinput').val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much how about redirecting ? I mean can we redirect our option ? for example when I clicked facebook than go facebook

Comment: I couldn't add any question for today but thank you so much

Comment: @recruit_man Use input on change event,Save the links in value,after redirect to them.

Comment: but where shall I get the links ? where will add my link inside js or ?